# How to select the checkbox in the list of checkboxes ONE-BY-ONE in selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, checkbox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to select all the checkboxes from here one-by-one after every 3 second. I tried couple of xpaths with list,none of them have worked

[image: divs]

Tried xpaths:

1. `//div/div[@class='filters-list sdCheckbox ']`
2. Using input and type. But none of them worked. Can you please help me out?

   Reference website: https://www.snapdeal.com/products/storage-devices?sort=plrty
   ->Capacity at the left hand corner
3. `By.xpath("//a[@class='filter-name']")`  this one listed out all the filters of page.

Comment: Try selecting the checkboxes by contained text. It will be easier in your case. Write a function that takes the checkbox label text, e.g. 8GB, or whatever, and selects the checkbox based on that.

Comment: I need to infact select all of them one-by-one after every 3 second.So can't this be done using list

Comment: Please clarify your scenario and provide details. There are a lot of checkboxes on that page. Which ones are you trying to click? Are you intending to click one to select it and then click it again to deselect it then click the next one or do you intend to have all the boxes checked at the end?

Comment: I want all the checkboxes to be selected at the end. After selecting the first checkbox, I don't have to deselect it, select the next checkbox after 3 seconds

Comment: @Ritu Got it. Can you update the exact steps you trying to perform?

Answer (score 1):

The xPath `"//div[@data-name='Capacity_s']/div[@class='filters-list sdCheckbox  ']/input"` will fetch you the list of all input elements that you need to check.

Answer (score 0):

There is a container DIV that holds all the filters of a certain type, e.g. Brand, Capacity, etc. The one for Brand is shown below.

```
<div class="filter-inner " data-name="Brand">
```

Under that container, all the LABEL tags are what you need to click to check the boxes. So, we can craft a CSS selector using the grouping as a filter to reach only the checkboxes we want.

```
"div[data-name='Brand'] label"
```

Since this is something I assume you will reuse, I would write this as a function.

```
public static void CheckFilters(String filterGroup)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    List<WebElement> filters = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[data-name='" + filterGroup + "'] label"));
    // System.out.println(filters.size()); // for debugging
    for (int i = 0; i < filters.size(); i++)
    {
        filters.get(i).click();

        // wait for the two overlays to disappear
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.searcharea-overlay")));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.filterLoader.hidden")));

        // reload the element list after the refresh so you don't get StaleElementExceptions
        filters = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[data-name='" + filterGroup + "'] label"));
    }
}
```

and you would call it like

```
driver.get("https://www.snapdeal.com/products/storage-devices?sort=plrty");
CheckFilters("Brand");
```